# Changing the sprite image in XNA

Tags: c#, animation, xna, sprite

This is my code for the movement of my sprite for my game. I looked at tutorials and lessons on line to help me with this. I need to know how to make the character sprite change every time a certain key is pressed. (eg. left key: left facing sprite, right key: right facing sprite) I have looked on line but I;m not sure how to integrate it into my code. I believe I can do something with the enumerated list in my "MageChar" class to change the sprite but i'm not sure how to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Game Class

```
namespace RPG
{
    public class MageChar : charMovement
    {
        //variable where sprite file name is stored
        const string MageAssetName = "MageChar";
        //starting x position
        const int StartPositionX = 0;
        //starting y position
        const int StartPositionY = 0;
        //speed that the sprite will move on screen
        const int MageSpeed = 160;
        //move sprite 1 up/down when the arrow key is pressed
        const int MoveUp = 1;
        const int MoveDown = -1;
        const int MoveLeft = -1;
        const int MoveRight = 1;

        //used to store the current state of the sprite
        enum State
        {
            Walking
        }
        //set to current state of the sprite. initally set to walking
        State CurrentState = State.Walking;

        //stores direction of sprite
        Vector2 Direction = Vector2.Zero;

        //stores speed of sprite
        Vector2 Speed = Vector2.Zero;

        //stores previous state of keyboard
        KeyboardState PreviousKeyboardState;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager)
        {
            //sets position to the top left corner of the screen
            Position = new Vector2(StartPositionX, StartPositionY);

            base.LoadContent(theContentManager, MageAssetName);
        }

        //checks state of the keyboard
        private void UpdateMovement(KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState)
        {
            //run if the sprite is walking
            if (CurrentState == State.Walking)
            {
                //sets direction and speed to zero
                Speed = Vector2.Zero;
                Direction = Vector2.Zero;

                //if left key is pressed, move left
                if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.X = MageSpeed;
                    //moves the sprite left
                    Direction.X = MoveLeft;
                }
                //if right key is pressed, move right
                else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.X = MageSpeed;
                    //moves the sprite right
                    Direction.X = MoveRight;
                }
                //if up key is pressed, move up
                if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.Y = MageSpeed;
                    //moves sprite up
                    Direction.Y = MoveUp;
                }
                //if down key is pressed, move down
                else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.Y = MageSpeed;
                    //moves sprite down
                    Direction.Y = MoveDown;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
        {
            //obtains current state of the keyboard
            KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

            //calls in UpdateMovement and passes in current keyboard state
            UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState);

            //set previous state to current state
            PreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;

            //call update method of the charMovement class
            base.Update(theGameTime, Speed, Direction);
        }


    }
}
```

CharMovement

```
namespace RPG
{
    public class charMovement
    {
        //The asset name for the Sprite's Texture
        public string charSprite;

        //The Size of the Sprite (with scale applied)
        public Rectangle Size;

        //The amount to increase/decrease the size of the original sprite. 
        private float mScale = 1.0f;
            //The current position of the Sprite
            public Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0,0);

            //The texture object used when drawing the sprite
            private Texture2D charTexture;


        //Load the texture for the sprite using the Content Pipeline
        public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string theCharSprite)
        {
            //loads the image of the sprite
            charTexture = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>("charSprite");

            charSprite = theCharSprite;
            //creates a new rectangle the size of the sprite
            Size = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(charTexture.Width * mScale), (int)(charTexture.Height * mScale));
        }

        //Update the Sprite and change it's position based on the set speed, direction and elapsed time.
        public void Update(GameTime theGameTime, Vector2 theSpeed, Vector2 theDirection)
        {
            Position += theDirection * theSpeed * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }

        //Draw the sprite to the screen
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
        {       
            //draw the sprite to the screen inside a rectangle     
            theSpriteBatch.Draw(charTexture, Position, 
                new Rectangle(0, 0, charTexture.Width, charTexture.Height), 
                Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, mScale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }
        }

    }
```

MageChar

```
namespace RPG
{
    public class MageChar : charMovement
    {
        //variable where sprite file name is stored
        const string MageAssetName = "MageChar";
        //starting x position
        const int StartPositionX = 0;
        //starting y position
        const int StartPositionY = 0;
        //speed that the sprite will move on screen
        const int MageSpeed = 160;
        //move sprite 1 up/down when the arrow key is pressed
        const int MoveUp = 1;
        const int MoveDown = -1;
        const int MoveLeft = -1;
        const int MoveRight = 1;

        //used to store the current state of the sprite
        enum State
        {
            Walking
        }
        //set to current state of the sprite. initally set to walking
        State CurrentState = State.Walking;

        //stores direction of sprite
        Vector2 Direction = Vector2.Zero;

        //stores speed of sprite
        Vector2 Speed = Vector2.Zero;

        //stores previous state of keyboard
        KeyboardState PreviousKeyboardState;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager)
        {
            //sets position to the top left corner of the screen
            Position = new Vector2(StartPositionX, StartPositionY);

            base.LoadContent(theContentManager, MageAssetName);
        }

        //checks state of the keyboard
        private void UpdateMovement(KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState)
        {
            //run if the sprite is walking
            if (CurrentState == State.Walking)
            {
                //sets direction and speed to zero
                Speed = Vector2.Zero;
                Direction = Vector2.Zero;

                //if left key is pressed, move left
                if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.X = MageSpeed;
                    //moves the sprite left
                    Direction.X = MoveLeft;
                }
                //if right key is pressed, move right
                else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.X = MageSpeed;
                    //moves the sprite right
                    Direction.X = MoveRight;
                }
                //if up key is pressed, move up
                if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.Y = MageSpeed;
                    //moves sprite up
                    Direction.Y = MoveUp;
                }
                //if down key is pressed, move down
                else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) == true)
                {
                    //speed of sprite movement
                    Speed.Y = MageSpeed;
                    //moves sprite down
                    Direction.Y = MoveDown;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
        {
            //obtains current state of the keyboard
            KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

            //calls in UpdateMovement and passes in current keyboard state
            UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState);

            //set previous state to current state
            PreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;

            //call update method of the charMovement class
            base.Update(theGameTime, Speed, Direction);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change your `charTexture`.. so that as the next iteration of `Draw` comes around.. it draws the new texture.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead -- is it possible to explain what you mean by drawing the next texture, as I am new to the language.

Comment: Your game constantly calls the `Draw` method in a loop. That method uses the `charTexture` variable to draw your character. You just need to change the `charTexture` variable. When you do.. the `Draw` method will continue to draw using `charTexture`.. but `charTexture` is a new texture.. so a new sprite will appear.

Comment: How would I change "charTexture" it to make the image change along with the users keyboard arrow input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create sprite texture: put all images of your character in one texture (like this: https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTl7XCFrVrnkzcNtpokcpJf3SKxcALw-IpbuSgVP4xNRBgtsnN4). Lets say that for now your character have two different states - facing left and facing right and both textures is 64x64. So we have something like this:

```
-----------------
|       |       |
|  <--  |  -->  |
|       |       |
-----------------
```

Total texture size: 128x64

You **need** to add more values to state enum. Lets say your state enum will have two values *Left* and *Right* instead of just *Walking*.
Now you can switch frames in your draw method using third parameter:

```
if (CurrentState == State.Left)
    theSpriteBatch.Draw(charTexture, Position, 
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64), // first frame 
            Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, mScale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
else if (CurrentState == State.Right)
    theSpriteBatch.Draw(charTexture, Position, 
            new Rectangle(64, 0, 64, 64), // second frame 
            Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, mScale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

You also can use direction or anything you want instead of state. In the future you would want to have different textures for whole walking animation and other actions for single character.

More about sprite animations: http://thundernoodle.net/notblog/2011/10/17/how-to-animate-a-sprite-using-a-sprite-sheet-in-xna/

You can also switch textures, as suggested, for different states. To do so just load two different textures, for example charTexture_Left and charTexture_Right and use them in draw method depending on CurrentState.

To make CurrentState change along with a user arrow input add CurrentState to UpdateMovement method:

```
if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) == true)
{
    //speed of sprite movement
    Speed.X = MageSpeed;
    //moves the sprite left
    Direction.X = MoveLeft;
    CurrentState = State.Left; // set current state to left
 }
 else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) == true)
 {
     //speed of sprite movement
     Speed.X = MageSpeed;
     //moves the sprite right
     Direction.X = MoveRight;
     CurrentState = State.Right; // set current state to right
  }
```